# CSS - prevent dynamic DIVs to render on website

Tags: html, css

Not sure if this is possible or not, my requirement is something like this - I have  a web page having three div which are wrapped inside another main div having display:flex so that all the three div can appear adjacent to each other. Now the issue is that in the middle div I am extracting some data from my database which itself contains DIVs. the divs may not be properly closed i:e few  might not be closed with /div. So when the data appears on the middle div, the third div sometimes goes out of the flex box causing issue in the layout. Is there any possible way to avoid this ? Hope I am able to explain my issue.

Comment: The data contains HTML?

Comment: @SeanPianka Yes

Comment: Why not just properly close the divs on the other pages?

Comment: @GaryHayes the data in the middle div comes from database which is updated by my end users  with the help of a html editor (sceditor)

Comment: I see, so then write a script to check for opening and closing tags. If there aren't closing tags, add them before entering into database.

Comment: Or, and this may be easier... set a max-width on the middle div, and set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: Or, wrap the user content in your own div, so whatever is loaded into it WILL have a closing div.

Comment: The editor needs to be smarter. It needs to keep a score for "well formed" html. It won't submit to database with those errors in the first place.

Comment: Are you expecting to get some magic function that will fix the structure exactly as you expect it to?

Comment: @AlonEitan Everything is possible in programming mate, I am just not able to figure it out as of now but I am sure there will be a workaround

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, we never inject user generated content into a page without properly sanitising it to help prevent security vulnerabilities such as XSS. Please research HTML sanitisation and make sure you're processing this user generated content safely.

With that being said, browsers are quite forgiving of improperly formatted markup and will try their best to render what you give them. So to prevent this user generated content messing with your page you're going to want to isolate these documents from the rest of your page.

Instead of dropping this user generated html directly in the page you could provide it as a srcdoc to an iframe like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>foo</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .container {
        display: flex;
      }
      .one, .two, .three {
        height 200px;
      }
      .one {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .two {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .three {
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .inline {
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="one">
        <iframe class="inline" srcdoc="<div><h1>my parent was not properly closed</h1>"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
        <iframe class="inline" srcdoc="<div><div><h2>nor mine</h2>"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="three">
        <iframe class="inline" srcdoc="<div><div><div><h3>neither was mine</h3>"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd strongly encourage use of the [sandbox](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-iframe-sandbox) attribute for this usage too.